# Angular directive test with templateUrl, Failed to instantiate module

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Got some issues with unit test a directive with a templateURL. I am using karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor and I've read several guides about it. Added preproccsors, stripprefix etc. Gone over it several times so it should not be any wrong there.

In my test i add this line, as written in several guides:

```
  beforeEach(module('template/input-with-units/input-with-units.html'));
```

The error I get when I run the test is:

```
 Failed to instantiate module template/input-with-units/input-with-units.html
```

I've checked all paths several times. Nothing is wrong. Is there any clever way to debug this?

Comment: I know for sure that the `module()` function only accepts names of defined **modules**, not `templateUrl`s. Whatever guide you're reading, it's definitely incorrect.

Comment: @ryeballar karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor convert html files to js strings and generate a angular module.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'll answer it in case someone else stumbles upon it.

One way to solve this is to assign `moduleName` to some unique string in the `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor` object in karma.conf.js, as follows:

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
  // ...
  // Other settings here
  // ...
  moduleName: 'myHtmlTemplates'
}
```

and then use

```
beforeEach(module('myHtmlTemplates'));
```

However, it sounds like there is some issue with how your paths are interpreted in jasmine, so you might stumble into other problems later such as $templateCache not finding your templates. If this is the case, you may want to debug the produced paths by calling `process.emitWarning(filepath)` inside the `cacheIdFromPath` (also in `ngHtml2JsPreprocessor`) and modify them as you wish.

Personally, I had issues with absolute paths being produced because I put my html-files in another folder under the parent folder, as such: `../frontend/views/**/*.html`, whereas my test folder where the `karma.conf.js` was place was named `frontend.tests`. The two dots caused karma to create absolute paths. I solved this by setting `basePath : '..'` in the karma config file.

Also, be careful with case-sensitivity in `$templateCache`. If you make a GET request with the wrong case in your code, you will not be able to find it in `$templateCache` and it will tell you that `$httpBackend` didn't expect that request.